# `Operating-System` attribute in AD vs MAC OS

Tags: active-directory, mac, attributes

There is a `Operating-System` attribute in `Active Directory` [attributes defined by Active Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-operatingsystem)

As I don't have access to AD containing MAC OS joined devices can anyone tell me what would it populate under this attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an `Operating-System` attribute (attributes don't usually start with an uppercase letter btw), only `operatingSystem`, that is set to:

```
Mac OS X
```

The relaed `operatingSystemVersion` is the appropriate macOS release, e.g.

```
10.14.2
```

The release number doesn't seem to update, it reflects the release number at the time of joining to AD.

Comment: Operating-System is the name of the attribute as it appears in the schema, and operatingSystem is the LDAP display name for the attribute, as per the [OPs link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-operatingsystem).